# How can I type E_in in Jupyter markdown

Tags: latex, markdown, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know how to type following text in Jupyter markdown?
I tried $\mathit{E}_in$, but it's not working.
Please help me, thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you want. Without messing about with fonts, you can just use:

`$E_{in}(h)$`

This makes everything use the regular maths font. `mathit` uses an italic font too, but removes spaces between letters so that words render more like words than lots of separate letters. However, in your example using `mathit` like so: `$\mathit{E_{in}(h)}$` produces the same result as not using it.

The picture you posted uses non-italic text, and the way to get that is to use `mathrm`:

`$\mathrm{E_{in}(h)}$`

Also, in the future, it would be helpful to know what you meant by "it's not working", since it's hard to tell if you mean it doesn't render at all or if it renders but not how you want it to look and how the result you got differs from the one you want.